# Is there a way to edit an sql response/result at the database level

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

First of all, disclaimer: This is for a testing/dev scenario, not for production use.

Is there a way to intercept a select query and for a specific field append some values to the response?

The calling apps are different and I am hoping we don't have to change their logic.

Also since this is temporary scenario we are evaluating we don't want to have to run an update on the database.

I'm thinking of triggers but I am can't see any that work at the select level.

Comment: please tag with database platform, but probably not other than a view

Comment: Create a view .

Comment: And note that tables have _columns_. not fields.

Comment: Within SQL Server itself, no, there is no support for this at all. The database **WILL** return exactly what the query tells it to. If you employ a service layer or caching layer, the product might be able to use the source app as part of the key and therefore create different results, but SQL Server won't play those games, nor should it.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn. My thinking was that if one can amend a value using a before insert trigger there should be one to amend a value at retrieval. Thanks for clarifying that up. I guess we'll go manual for now. It's not that significant to require application code changes.

Regarding the options to use a view, as I had mentioned the plan is to not change the calling apps and creating a view means we have to change the apps as well. I stand to be corrected though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways in Oracle to silently change the output of queries. Using the package [DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_advanced_rewrite), you can append values to existing values, although you will have to create a rewrite-equivalence for every single statement you want to modify. For example, the below query originally returns the name "Jon", but after creating a rewrite equivalence, the same query returns the name "Jon TEST!".

```
SYS> create table test1(name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SYS> insert into test1 values('Jon');

1 row created.

SYS> commit;

Commit complete.

SYS> select name from test1;

NAME
--------------------
Jon

1 row selected.

SYS> begin
  2     sys.dbms_advanced_rewrite.declare_rewrite_equivalence
  3     (
  4         name             => 'REWRITE1',
  5         source_stmt      => q'[select name from test1]',
  6         destination_stmt => q'[select name || ' TEST!' name from test1]',
  7         validate         => false,
  8         rewrite_mode     => 'GENERAL'
  9     );
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SYS> alter session set query_rewrite_integrity = trusted;

Session altered.

SYS> select name from test1;

NAME
--------------------------
Jon TEST!

1 row selected.
```

Needless to say, creating these rewrite equivalences can be kind of evil and can drive people crazy. You are literally telling Oracle to return the wrong values so be careful to let everybody know exactly what is happening.